# Dll Version Control in MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have an application that uses MEF to load plugins and it works just fine. All plugins reference the core library and exports the right part and the application loads the parts without any issue at all.

The issue that comes up has to do with the individual dependencies of the plugin libraries. An example is Ionic.Zip and Newtonsoft.Json. Since Nugget is used when developing these external parts, different plugins tend to reference different version of these libraries. The application may even load its own (in the case of Newtonsoft.Json).

What I've realized it that the plugin libraries are looking for a specific version of these libraries and hence throw errors when certain tasks are run.

Is there a way to indicate during development that a plugin should not be bound to any particular version of the library so that it will just make use of whatever is loaded?

That way it does not matter which version of Newtonsoft.Json or Ionic.Zip a plugin is linked to, it will just use the version that has been loaded by the main application.

Comment: Did you try hooking up to AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and load the assembly using Assembly.Load

Comment: No. I just use the ``AggregateCatalog`` together with ``AssemblyCatalog`` and ``DirectoryCatalog`` to load the plugins from a designated folder. The error doesn't happen when loading the plugins. They load just fine. Let's say a library uses a different version of Ionic.Zip, it will load fine but will throw an exception when I actually call a method on it that uses Ionic.Zip.

Comment: Which exception do you get?
In our solution we use BindingRedirect to solve these kindda issues. Create an assemblybinding for the assembly you need to fix and redirect all the version (from 0.0.0.0 to latest one) to the version you have.

Comment: The error is usually could not load library of a particular version.

Comment: BindingRedirect should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Assembly Binding Redirect.

You can create an assembly binding redirect for a given assembly by adding an entry in the app.config of your application. Following example will redirect all calls made to any version of myAssembly to v3.0.0.0 of the assembly

```
 <configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
          culture="en-us" />
        <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
          publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You can find more information at this link
[Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Should this be done within the main application that loads the plugins or the plugins themselves?
How about libraries that are not known to the main application but referenced as dependancies by plugins (eg plugin 1 references NLog vX.Y and plugin 2 references vX.Z? What I observe is that since we are just copying the plugins, we end up with just 1 copy of the library. The exact one depending on which one is copied last.

Comment: main application that loads the plugin (basically exe.config).

You could try to keep the latest version of all the dependent assemblies in a lib folder and copy all of them to the target folder in the end.

Comment: That is interesting. So it means the main application should be aware of all dependent libraries. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can the same xml be applied to web.config if it is an asp.net mvc web application that uses MEF to load additional components?

Comment: Yes. It should be applicable to all .Net apps

Comment: It worked great for the asp.net mvc web app. Thanks.